# Xrm.Navigation.openForm not honouring formid

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to follow the examples found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform) that explain how to use `Xrm.Navigation.openForm` method to open a CRM form for a new entity.

My target entity has multiple forms and I'm trying to specify the form ID in the `entityFormOptions` object as described in the link above. I've copied the relevant text here (with the relevant line in bold):

> ## entityFormOptions
>
> Entity form options for opening the form.  The
>   object contains the following attributes:
>
> - cmdbar: (Optional) Boolean. Indicates whether to display the command    bar. If you do not specify this parameter, the command bar is displayed by default.
> - createFromEntity: (Optional) Lookup. Designates a record that will  provide default values based on mapped attribute values. The lookup object has the following String properties: entityType, id, and name  (optional).
> - entityId: (Optional) String. ID of the entity record to display the form for.
> - entityName: (Optional) String. Logical name of the entity to display the form for.
> - **formId: (Optional) String. ID of the form instance to be displayed**.
> - height: (Optional) Number. Height  of the form window to be displayed in pixels.
> - navBar: (Optional) String. Controls whether the navigation bar is displayed and whether application navigation is available using the
>     areas and subareas  defined in the sitemap. Valid values are: "on",
>     "off", or "entity".

However this doesn't seem to work for me.
The ID of my form is `375DE297-C0AF-4711-A811-5F1663FAE5DA`

Here's my code:

```
var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "contact";
entityFormOptions["formId"] = "375DE297-C0AF-4711-A811-5F1663FAE5DA";
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions);
```

The new entity form opens; however it uses the default form, not the specified form.

I am running as a System Administrator and I have confirmed that I have access to all the forms for the specified entity so I don't think it is a form-security issue.

Has anyone tried this method of opening forms in Dynamics 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's looks like mistake in docs or bug in Dynamics.

Previous implementation (v8 and before) took **formid** in parameters object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#openEntityForm

Although current documentation states that formId must be set in entityFormOptions it isn't actually honoured. But it is honoured when you put it to good old formParameters.

Thus this does the trick:

```
var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "contact";
var formParameters = {};
formParameters ["formid"] = "375DE297-C0AF-4711-A811-5F1663FAE5DA";
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters);
```

P.S. Note that lowercase **"formid"**.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late but hopefully will help someone else.

The documentation is correct. You can supply formId as shown. You only need to make sure that form is added to the Model Driven App in App Designer (You add the form by checking it on the panel on the right) [image: Screenshot of App Designer where you need to add the form]

```
var pageInput = {
    pageType: "entityrecord",
    entityName:"icon_case",
    entityId: recordId,
    formId: v_formId
    };
```

Comment: Even after adding the form in App Designer, this is not working when specifying formId...

Answer (score 1):

we can also use the below code to open a particular entity form:

```
var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "nrw_contact";//Logical name of the entity
entityFormOptions["entityId"] = "nrw_contact_ID"; //ID of the entity record
entityFormOptions["formId"] = "CF8D885B-256D-43E6-8776-CBBB7AA88EF5"; //FormId
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions);
```

Please refer this link for more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform

Comment: Hi Pradip - did you try this? Your example code is the same as my question. The documentation says you are correct, but unless things have changed since I wrote my question, it does not work in practice