# Xrm.Navigation.openForm not honouring formid in Unified Interface

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics-crm-uci

I have been using the technique in the following post:

[Xrm.Navigation.openForm not honouring formid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359342/xrm-navigation-openform-not-honouring-formid)

which has beeen working great in the Classic Interface.

I have updated my JavaScript to the following:

```js
function OpenSpecificForm(primaryControl)
    {
        const FORMID = "A696976B-EA8A-42F3-B4DC-F35DC9204D58";                      

        var formContext       = primaryControl;
        var parameters        = { formid: FORMID };
        var entityFormOptions = {};
        entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "new_entity_name";

        var recordId = formContext.data.entity.getId();                    
        var recordName   = formContext.getAttribute("new_name").getValue();    

        if (recordId != null)   { parameters["new_targetentityfieldid"] = recordId; }
        if (recordName != null) { parameters["new_targetentityfieldname"] = recordName; }

        Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, parameters);
    }
```

and set ribbon workbench as follows:

[Crm Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVkhI.png)

This code continues to work as expected in the Classic UI but doesnt seem to work in the new Unified Interface.  The entity form opens but opens the last one CRM remembers and NOT the one I have specified in the formId.

Has anyone managed to open a specific form in the new UI?

Comment: Have you tried with "formId" instead of "formid"? The parameter name changed when Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm was replaced by Xrm.Navigation.openForm

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately changing the parameter to formId doesn't help.  It stops it working in both the old and new UI.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of potential problems with your code.

The first one is related to how the form context is being generated because it actually needs to be obtained using the getFormContext method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/customize-dev/pass-dynamics-365-data-page-parameter-ribbon-actions#form-and-grid-context-in-ribbon-actions) seems wrong) from the `primaryControl` object:

```
var formContext = primaryControl.getFormContext();
```

The second one is the parameter is the **formId** parameter name, which according to [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform#parameters) should be written using capital I. It might no be a problem, but remember that the [json spec](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) states the following:

> All member names exchanged between the Client and the Server that are
>   considered for matching of any kind should be considered to be
>   case-sensitive. The terms function, method, and procedure can be
>   assumed to be interchangeable.

Comment: Hi, adding getFormContext() works in the old UI, however in the UI I get a script error: primaryControl.getFormContext is not a function.

Comment: when using the ribbon and passing the primaryControl to your js function, use the primaryControl object as though it were the formContext. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54012344/44815